# mplayer - Scale video to window size

Tags: mplayer

When I open a video with mplayer2 it "scales" to my window size. E.g.

[image]

The original being 720p. When I open the same file with mplayer it displays the video in its default resolution it seems, only cropped:

[image]

I read the manual page and tried the `-zoom` option, but the results are not what I expected:

[image]

I could maybe use the `-xy` or some scaling option, but I want the video "scale" to adapt to the window size (if I change the window size I want the video to adapt, like with mplayer2). Is this possible with mplayer?

Comment: If you're open to suggestions, I'd recommend just using the delightful [mpv](http://www.mpv.org/)!

Answer (score 7):

Ah, good old Age of Empires. :)

You can fit the window to scale as you want through the following command, From [Ubuntu's Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1010620):

mplayer -vf scale -zoom -xy 600 my_file.avi

where -xy 600 is the x axis value. Replace the 600 with desired value you want. Also, you can enter the custom value directly into your mplayer's config file as stated:

> you could also put in your ~/.mplayer/config file
>   there are various ways to do it
>   Code:
>
> screenw=600
>
> screenh=400
>
> xy=.5
>
> xy=600
>
> and for fullscreen
>   Code:
>
> fs=1

Comment: Either I did not understand it or it does not seem to work. `xwininfo` show my window size to be 958x538. If I use 958 instead of 600 it has the same effect as only using "zoom". And it obviously does not adapt to the window size.

Comment: @Alex did you read the Ubuntu forum thread I linked? The details are in there.